# Divergence of series

Tags: random, divergent-series

Given that a is a non 0 real number and ck is a series of real number for all k natural number where $\sum_{k= 1}^{\infty} c_k^2 = \infty $. If $c_k \to 0$, proof that $lim _{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}cos(ac_k) = 0$

My question is, how can I translate $cos(ac_k)$ into $c_k^2$? It seems like I need to use imaginary number (euclid theorem) to solve this but I m not sure. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $\cos x=1-\frac12x^2+o(x^2)$ when $x\to0$.

Comment: Also $\ln(\cos(x)) = -1/2 x^2 + o(x^2)$.